# Consuming REST service with .NET 4 Client Profile

Tags: .net, rest, .net-client-profile

What's the easiest/best way to consume a RESTful service from a .NET client application using the .NET 4 Client Profile?  Everything I have found ends up pushing me towards the full framework:

- WCF REST Starter Kit.  HttpClient class requires full framework.
- WebChannelFactory<> is in System.ServiceModel.Web, now removed from the Client Profile.
- WCF Data Services Client Library is in System.Data.Services.Client (not in the Client profile either)

Is WebClient in System.Net my only option?

Comment: Have you looked at this? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307023

Comment: I'm pretty sure WebClient is a wrapper for the WebRequest class used in that link.

Comment: What part of HttpClient requires the full framework?  Is it the reference to System.Web?  I'm curious because the only reason for that is one call to System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncodeToBytes

Comment: Hmm, yes it's just that one call.

Comment: @ckr  When I ran into that problem I found that Mono had an nice drop in replacement.  If you get my drift :-)  http://www.koders.com/csharp/fid56F209244C740BA63A0B58B4621A7F9836CA8086.aspx

Comment: RestSharp will support Client Profile very soon thanks to Darrel

Answer (score 3):

You can use Hammock for REST (http://hammock.codeplex.com), it supports the Client Profile.